# What is the Use of WSDL in WSO2ESB

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have implemented lot of proxy services.So those are working fine while creating of custom proxy we have option call WSDL.What is the use of that option i have tried it but its not taking my value .its accepting only valid WSDL's only .i tried to customize like this

```
http://192.168.1.222:8280/services/Login/username=?&passwordname=?
```

but its not accepting giving error like NOt a proper WSDl
after that tried with echo service Endpoint and its accepting this one

```
http://192.168.1.221:8282/services/echo?wsdl1
```

i am really wondering about this what is the use of this Publish WSDL Option.Is it useful for accepting the input from client or else something and i went with docs i couldn't find proper explanation and we have SOAPUI for testing as TRYTHIS But it has only one mediation Operation we can't able pass any parameters in to that like We have in WSO2dss try this how we will get that please explain to me THanks faisal

Comment: its taking all operation into present service Try this SOAP if i give input its showing <TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.</TryitProxyError> this error what is the use of this operations and WSDL

Answer (score 3):

[WSDL](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) is a fundamental principle in the context of Web Services. WSDL [describes the Web Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Description_Language) and how you should access those.

With [WSO2 ESB](http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus), when you create a [proxy service](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Proxy+Services), you have the option of publishing the WSDL to describe the web service you are trying to expose via the proxy.

If you do not specify a WSDL for the service, ESB will not know any operations you are trying to expose. This is why you only see a mediate operation. soapUI generates the request for an operation by looking at the XML schema for the request.

ESB will just mediate the requests to back-end service.

So, in summary, if you need your clients to know how your web service operations are defined, you should choose the option to publish a WSDL.

Comment: in my case i am getting request from mobile client using xpath i am accepting  the values and storing in properties and creating payload operation as per requirement and sending to dss endpoint.you are saying if we  publishwsdl means what are request operation we defined in wsdl file that opertion valuse like requests we will get in insequence..is it wright

Comment: As I mentioned, WSDL is there to describe the web services. You have to make sure you invoke the services according to the schema defined in WSDL.

Answer (score 0):

Publishing WSDL
It's about what are the services exposed using the proxy service. You can create a proxy service with or without publishing wsdl. If you didn't provide, you can not see any operations in 'try this service' options (which can be seen after the proxy is created). But when you provide this publishing wsdl you will be able to see what are the operations (exposed over the wsdl) in 'try this service' option. Then you only have to edit the value of the requested fields and send the request which will hit the inSequence.

If you are using SOAPUI use the wsdl corresponding to your services (which can be seen in services list) to create the sopa UI project, then in your soapUI project it will show the operations you can perform.

PS: you can use axis2Server which comes with wso2esb for your testing (its mentioned [here](http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB460/ESB+Samples+Setup)). Start the server and provide the wsdl url

```
http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService?wsdl
```

as publishing wsdl.

Comment: in my case i am getting request from mobile client using xpath i am accepting  the values and storing in properties and creating payload operation as per requirement and sending to dss endpoint.you are saying if we  publishwsdl means what are request operation we defined in wsdl file that opertion valuse like requests we will get in insequence..is it wright